# Execution flow when a request hit a node js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to Nodejs and here I have a piece of code in app.js :

```
var config = require('./config')
    , express = require('express')
    , db = require('./app/lib/db')
    , utils = require('./app/lib/utils')(config, db)    
var app = express() 
    http = require('http').createServer(app)
       require('./config/express')(app, config)
        require('./config/routes')(app, utils, model_list)
        http.listen(config.port, function () {
            console.log("API running at http://" + config.hostname)
        })
```

And a list of router api are set up in the file `config/routes`, for example:

```
app.get('/api/' + name + '/:limit([0-9]+)/:page([0-9]+)', ctrls[name].list); // get list with page
app.get('/api/' + name, ctrls[name].list); // get list with default page = 1
app.post('/api/' + name + '/search', ctrls[name].search); // search
app.get('/api/' + name + '/:id([0-9a-f]+)', ctrls[name].get); // get by id
```

After the server is created and starts to listen to the config port, what is the execution flow of a new request when it hits the server? How can the server catch a request in `app.js` and then move to `routes.js` to route it to a function to handle it?

Comment: It does not *moves* anything, you're setting `get`s and `post`s on an express reference(`app`) in `routes.js` which is the same you initiated in `app.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not move to `routes.js`... `routes.js` is required inside `app.js` and it applies the routes to the `app` object which is the express server. That is done once, before the server starts listening to port.

How express routes the request when it receives one is completely done internally. Basically it will check the request method (GET, POST, etc) then will check the requested URI and try to match a route, if the route matches, the function is executed.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it now

Answer (score 0):

you should check the anatomy of http in nodejs.
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/